# What is the smallest known organism with a skeleton?

Tags: taxonomy, anatomy, vertebrates

See question title. After doing some looking around on my own I haven't found much so I figured I'd ask some experts.

Comment: What kind of skeleton?

Comment: what he's asking is if you are talking about bones or including chitin (insects and things like crabs and shrimps) or other exoskeletal structures?

Comment: Shall we include the cytoskeleton?

Comment: further information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_organisms

Comment: The smallest vertebrate is the male Photocorynus spiniceps anglerfish at 6.2-7.3 mm, females are over 50 mm. Schindleria brevipinguis is 6.5-10 mm, and Paedophryne amauensis is 7.7 mm. Paedocypris progenetica is 7.9-10.3 mm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest vertebrate (if that's what you mean; there are many invertebrates with endoskeletons that are not made of bone) is *Paedophryne amanuensis*, a Papua New Guinea frog that's about 7 mm long.

Comment: do you have a reference for this?

Comment: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0029797